Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') - API problem
I never thought I'd have to make my own question, but here I am. I'm new to React.
I have a problem with getting a specific data from API. Other is fine, but with
src={https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${cityData?.weather[0]?.icon}@2x.png}
I get the error:

"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Here's full code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import sun from '../assets/sun.png'

export default function Weathertab(props){
    
    const [cityData, setCityData] = useState({})
    const apiKey = "b708966eb167246df9118941d4bddc31"
    const cityWeatherData = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=Metric&appid=${apiKey}`

    useEffect(function(){
        async function fetchData(){
            await fetch(cityWeatherData)
                .then(res=> res.json())
                .then(data => setCityData(data))
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    console.log(cityData)
    console.log(props.city)
    return(
        <div className="weather--tab">
            <img className="weather--icon" 
                    src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${cityData?.weather[0]?.icon}@2x.png`}
                    alt="sun behind a cloud" />
            <h1 className="weather--tab--degrees">{Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp)}°C</h1>
            <h3 className="weather--tab--city">{props.city}</h3>
            <div className="weather--min--max--temp">
                <div className="weather--block">
                    <label>Min Temp</label>
                    <p className="weather--min--max" id="weather--min">{Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp_min)}°C</p>
                </div>
                <div className="weather--block">
                    <label>Max Temp</label>
                    <p className="weather--min--max" id="weather--max">{Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp_max)}°C</p>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    )
}

I tried to Google the problem (and yt it as well) and nothing helped. The problem is only with the cityData.weather[0].icon.
I tried to make useState and setTheIcon to cityData.weather[0].icon in the useEffect function, but it didn't work.
Why it works okay with cityData?.main?.temp, but doesn't work for cityData?.weather[0]?.icon?

Error is happening because you are trying to load image using src but initially your cityData?.weather[0]?.icon is null
so this line is rendering error while other fields are showing NaN
src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${cityData?.weather[0]?.icon}@2x.png`}

use can try  using a state variable like loading using useState that will display loading while your data is being loaded
this is snippet for adding a loading state
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(function () {
    async function fetchData() {
      await fetch(cityWeatherData)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCityData(data);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return "loading data";
  }

here is correct code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
// import sun from "../assets/sun.png";

export default function Weathertab(props) {
  const [cityData, setCityData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const apiKey = "b708966eb167246df9118941d4bddc31";
  const cityWeatherData = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=Metric&appid=${apiKey}`;

  useEffect(function () {
    async function fetchData() {
      await fetch(cityWeatherData)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCityData(data);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return "loading data";
  }

  //   console.log(cityData.weather[0]);
  return (
    <div className="weather--tab">
      <img
        className="weather--icon"
        src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${cityData?.weather[0]?.icon}@2x.png`}
        alt="sun behind a cloud"
      />
      <h1 className="weather--tab--degrees">
        {Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp)}°C
      </h1>
      <h3 className="weather--tab--city">{props.city}</h3>
      <div className="weather--min--max--temp">
        <div className="weather--block">
          <label>Min Temp</label>
          <p className="weather--min--max" id="weather--min">
            {Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp_min)}°C
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="weather--block">
          <label>Max Temp</label>
          <p className="weather--min--max" id="weather--max">
            {Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp_max)}°C
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}


The reason for the problem you're seeing with cityData?.weather[0]?.icon is probably because cityData was initially an empty object {}. The reason cityData.weather is undefined when your component first renders is because the API call to retrieve weather data is still pending. Accessing [0] on an unknown value will result in an error.
You can conditionally render the weather icon once the data has been fetched to fix this. Before accessing any of its elements, you can use the && operator to see if cityData.weather exists. This is how to change your code:


import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import sun from '../assets/sun.png'

export default function Weathertab(props){
    
    const [cityData, setCityData] = useState({})
    const apiKey = "b708966eb167246df9118941d4bddc31"
    const cityWeatherData = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=Metric&appid=${apiKey}`

    useEffect(function(){
        async function fetchData(){
            await fetch(cityWeatherData)
                .then(res=> res.json())
                .then(data => setCityData(data))
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    console.log(cityData)
    console.log(props.city)
    return(
        <div className="weather--tab">
            {cityData.weather && (
                <img className="weather--icon" 
                    src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${cityData.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
                    alt="sun behind a cloud" />
            )}
            <h1 className="weather--tab--degrees">{Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp)}°C</h1>
            <h3 className="weather--tab--city">{props.city}</h3>
            <div className="weather--min--max--temp">
                <div className="weather--block">
                    <label>Min Temp</label>
                    <p className="weather--min--max" id="weather--min">{Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp_min)}°C</p>
                </div>
                <div className="weather--block">
                    <label>Max Temp</label>
                    <p className="weather--min--max" id="weather--max">{Math.floor(cityData?.main?.temp_max)}°C</p>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    )
}



By adding {cityData.weather && (...)} around the  tag, you ensure that the icon is only rendered when cityData.weather is truthy, thus avoiding the "Cannot read properties of undefined" error.
